# Pr2_controller for wheels robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just wondering, I am looking to move the base of my wheels robot by using the pr2_controller. (in Gazebo)
But I already looked onto the tutorial a little. I am still a bit confused. How do I incorporate the controller onto my  robot (segway RMP), do I consider it as a plugin or what? Or do I have to write controller of my own?

Some guidance will be extremely helpful for me to head into the correct direction.

Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63553/pr2_controller-for-wheels-robot/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should place a transmission element in your model. You can then load a PR2 controller to control the joint. I am not sure if this works in sdf. In urdf you should incorporate such an element:

```
<transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="caster_front_left_trans">
  <actuator name="caster_front_left_motor" />
  <joint name="caster_front_left_joint" />
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</transmission>
```

See the links [this thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/321/equivalent-transmission-or-actuator-tags-in-sdf/) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-27**:
thank you. I am following the tutorial here:http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20base%20controllers%20to%20drive%20the%20robot   .............
so to use it, do I have to attach the controller to my sdf robot first?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-27**:
For you own robot yes. Try to find the corresponding part in the urdf (or sdf) of the PR2 and copy that to your own robot.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-29**:
sorry, I am still confused. Would you mind to explain a little about the purpose of controller? I use the Diff-drive plugin got it moving in gazebo. I have been following the tutorials and everything is working in sdf, and the website rarely mention about PR2 controller.